# Scale image to browser size...then scroll to next image

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design

A bit of a long shot here, but hopefully someone will be able to help me with this one.

I'm looking to scale an image to the browser size (mobile devices too), this bit I can achieve, but I was wondering if it was at all possible if you then scroll down, it will pull you down to the next image, which will also be scaled to fit the browser size, if that makes sense? (Apologies).

I currently achieve scaled images using the backstretch plugin like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").backstretch("../images/background-v2.jpg");
});
```

Nesting them inside a div as I'd like them to be around 95% of the browser size to leave a white border around the image.
But as I'm planning on taking the site into wordpress to make a content manageable site, I don't want the image tags to be inserted via jQuery.
Ideally like this:

```
<div id="project-images">
<img src="../images/image-01.jpg" width="" height="" />
<img src="../images/image-02.jpg" width="" height="" />
<img src="../images/image-03.jpg" width="" height="" />
<img src="../images/image-04.jpg" width="" height="" />
</div>
```

With image-01 being scaled to fit the browser size, then upon scrolling it will pull you down to image-02 which will also then be scaled to the browser size.
A bit of a long shot, but I'm completely clueless as to how this would be achieved, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

that could be one way, there must be many

you set window height to the height of all images,

but you set images to display : none

then make a plugin that

- show one image/hide the other
- scroll the window to that image ($(window).scrollTop(...))
- reposition back to top : 0 all images

then

use plugin to show first image

then

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

//how much must the user scroll before next/prev image is shown :
var minscrolling = 50;

$(window).on({
       "scrollstart" : function(){
             lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

       },
       "scroll" : function (e) {
             var currentscrollpos= $(this).scrollTop();
             //reposition visible image so it seems it doesn't scroll
             // top : lastScrollTop -currentscrollpos
             // 
            if (lastScrollTop - currentscrollpos > minscrolling)  

                 // use  plugin to show next img
                 // set lastscrolltop to  currentscrollpos

            else if (lastScrollTop -  currentscrollpos < -minscrolling) 
                  //use plugin to show previous img
                   // set lastscrolltop to  currentscrollpos
       }

 });
```